# JWT's in server side cookies using the Strapi user-permissions plugin google auth

Tags: next.js, google-oauth, strapi, cookie-httponly

Following this [tutorial](https://talke.dev/strapi-user-permissions-jwt-cookies) about httpOnly cookie authentication (`/auth/local`), successfully, I am now stuck on what to do next when authenticating with a third-party provider. (`/auth/[provider]`)

Here's why.

First here's how the code looks like under third-party provider authentication

```
/extensions/user-permissions/controllers/Auth.js

    ctx.send({
      jwt: strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.jwt.issue({
      id: user.id,
    }),
      user: sanitizeEntity(user.toJSON ? user.toJSON() : user, {
      model: strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').model,
      }),
   });
```

Which clearly is not the same as this one below where we use `httpOnly cookie`

/extensions/user-permissions/controllers/Auth.js

```
    const token = strapi.plugins["users-permissions"].services.jwt.issue({
        id: user.id,
        });
   ctx.cookies.set("token", token, {
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false,
     maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 14, // 14 Day Age
     domain: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" ? "localhost" : 
     process.env.PRODUCTION_URL,
   });
  ctx.send({
     status: 'Authenticated',
     user: sanitizeEntity(user.toJSON ? user.toJSON() : user, {
     model: strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').model,
     }),
  });
```

My frontend authentication logic consists of an authentication context provider which wraps around all the components of my app.

I have done this such that any action type dispatched i.e LOGIN/LOGOUT, any component that has anything to do with the state of user auth should listen and respond accordingly to the dispatch action type.

For example, the `<Navbar />` component may want to display links of login and logout based on those dispatched states.

**MY PROBLEM:**

How do I work around a solution that issues httpOnly cookies on authentication using a third-party provider like google, just like the local provider would after following this [tutorial](https://talke.dev/strapi-user-permissions-jwt-cookies)?

I am also aware of the logic we edited inside `/extensions/user-permissions/config/policies/permissions.js` to 'embed' the token as an authorization token to make requests to private APIs